"Snow White and Seven Dwarfs" animated sequel (?) with giant dwarfs
I remember watching it on video in late 80s (I was a small kid then), on the same cassette tape as Disney's classic "Snow White and the Seven Dwarfs", almost as if someone recorded them together as two parts, but this one was definitely not Disney.
It was animated, in color, and it told the story of some kids (probably a boy and a girl) who were, I think, children of Snow White and her prince, and they met the Seven Dwarfs from the original story.
But the kick is: the dwarfs are actually giants in this version of the story. As in, they are not tiny people, but actually much larger than the kids, probably even larger than grown-ups. 
I don't remember anything else than that, just that significant detail that dwarfs were gigantic.
Rings a bell for anyone? :)

Yes. It does ring a bell. 
It is A Snow White Christmas(1979). It is a Christmas generated film produced by Filmation. It is a sequel to the fairy tale Snow White, unrelated to Filmation's other sequel to Snow White, Happily Ever After (1990). Its release date is December 19 1980. It is made a 48-minute show. 
Quoting from the Wikipedia page of the film, 

The film's plot revolves around the return of the Wicked Queen, who is unexpectedly brought back to life and casts an evil spell that freezes the entire land. It is up to young Snow White, the daughter of the original Snow White aided by the seven giants, to defeat her once-and-for-all and save the kingdom.

Here is the trailer on Youtube. Full show is also available on youtube too. You could watch it here. 
Below is one of posters of the animated show. 
 

Yes! That's it! The other child was the dwarf Grunyon!
I watched it on Youtube and it's exactly as psychedelic as I remember. Thank you, good sir or ma'am! :)
